# How to reference the leaflet layer of a react-leaflet component?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I used **react-leaflet** to visualize a quite long path on a map. Users can select from a list and I would like to have different color for the selected path. Changing the state and rendering again is too slow, I am looking for a faster solution.

Leaflet path elements have setStyle() method, so my first idea was using it instead of rendering again. But how to reference the leaflet layer?

```
class MyPathComponent extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.selected){
      this.setState({selected: true});
      LEAFLET_POLYLINE.setStyle({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Polyline polylines={this.props.path} />
    );
  }
}
```

So what should I write instead of **LEAFLET_POLYLINE** in this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Components in `react-leaflet` have a property called `leafletElement`.  I believe you can do something like this:

```
class MyPathComponent extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.selected){
      this.setState({selected: true});
      this.refs.polyline.leafletElement.setStyle({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Polyline ref="polyline" polylines={this.props.path} />
    );
  }
}
```

Two things to note:

1. I haven't tested this code, so it may need some small tweaks.
2. Using a string for "ref" is considered legacy in React, so you'll probably want to do something slightly different (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute)). The `leafletElement` is the important part here.

Instead of the code above, it may be better to just extend the `Polyline`  component for your custom component (limited docs [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Components.md#polyline)):

```
import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet';

class MyPathComponent extends Polyline {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.selected){
      this.setState({selected: true});
      this.leafletElement.setStyle({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Let me know if any of this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Full example using React callback ref and adding to @Eric's answer above:

```
export default class MyMap extends Component {

  leafletMap = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.debug(this.leafletMap);
  }

  setLeafletMapRef = map => (this.leafletMap = map && map.leafletElement);

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        ref={this.setLeafletMapRef}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution="Powered by <a href=&quot;https://www.esri.com&quot;>Esri</a>"
          url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```